# Websphere - javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet not a servlet class

Tags: servlets, websphere

I get this error message when trying to connect to our webservices.

```
Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0201E: Servlet [...] not a servlet class.
```

However, the class mentioned inside the brackets is a servlet class:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "xxx", endpointInterface = "xxx")
```

What I read was that in Websphere the class loader should be configured to Parent last; this is what I did and then to get rid of all jar - files that use *Servlet*.jar - I think I did this, too, since the only files that I am using are these ones:

```
antisamy-1.4.3.jar
api-7.9.0.0.jar
avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar
batik-css-1.7.jar
batik-ext-1.7.jar
batik-util-1.7.jar
bsh-core-2.0b4.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-beanutils-core-1.7.0.jar
commons-codec-1.2.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-configuration-1.5.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-lang-2.3.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
core-7.9.0.0.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
esapi-2.0_rc11.jar
istack-commons-runtime-2.16.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.9.jar
jaxb-core-2.2.8-b01.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2-promoted-b65.jar
jaxen-1.1-beta-8.jar
jdom-1.0.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
log4j-api-2.7.jar
log4j-core-2.7.jar
logkit-1.0.1.jar
nekohtml-1.9.12.jar
serializer-2.7.2.jar
xalan-2.7.2.jar
xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar
xom-1.1.jar
```

Maybe someone could give me a hint or knows that the problem can be?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you're relying on the annotation you mentioned, that's going to create a web service, not a servlet.  Unless of course the class the @WebService is defined in extends javax.servlet.Servlet.  Did you mean @WebServlet instead?  Posting the pertinent portion of your source would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, you are right, that is creating a Webservice, however I get this error message when calling the URL: class and interface have both the annotation WebService, and when calling the URL on WAS I always get the aforementioned message that Servlet is not a servlet class.

Comment: Does the aforementioned class have any one of the servlet annos or implement Servlet ?  @WebService is not a servlet anno and a class decorated with it alone can't act as a servlet directly.

Comment: Well, I checked all classes and no class has had any @WebServlet annotation - that was the thing that confused me when this error always showed up in Websphere. Furthermore, I checked the web.xml and there where some servlet mappings, so I deleted the whole web.xml, too. And when I called the URL with ?wsdl the only thing that I get is: HTTP ERROR 404. If I call the URL without ?wsdl I reach Directory: /... META-INF... - I was told I should get some output for wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possibility:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/171243/srve0201e-servlet-my-webservice-not-a-servlet-clas.html

This text in particular:

> The issue was showing up at deploy time and had to do with the fact
>   that my web services was referencing classes in a shared library. The
>   deploy code doesn't have access to the shared library so it wasn't
>   able to resolve things and gave up.
>
> After some mad refactoring it started working.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the message, but I am sorry I already know this one. What we try to accomplish is the following: a simple class with a @Webservice annotation, exporting it in Eclipse into a war file without generating a web.xml, then uploading it to Websphere 8.5.5 and calling the URL with ?wsdl but I never get the right output. I followed this turoial too but it never worked: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0709_gawor/0709_gawor-pdf.pdf - I know it is from 2007 but this should not be a great problem, hopefully.